# How to set UITextField border with gradient from left to right with rounded corners using Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, cagradientlayer

I am trying to implement a UITextField activity with rounded gradient border from left to right like below sample: -

[image]

**Requirement:**
Here I have 2 text fields. On load view controller 'Email' will be active with the gradient border. When user resigns 'Email' field then the border will change to white color and again if user click in 'Email' text field then the border will change to the gradient.

I tried below code but not working properly: -

```
class CustomTextField: UITextField {

    var gradient:CAGradientLayer! = nil

    func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {

        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .bottomLeft, .topRight, .bottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: frame.size.height / 2, height: frame.size.height / 2))

        gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.frame =  CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: frame.size)
        gradient.colors = [UIColor.green.cgColor, UIColor.red.cgColor]

        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.lineWidth = 10
        shape.path = path.cgPath
        shape.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        shape.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        gradient.mask = shape

        layer.addSublayer(gradient)

        super.becomeFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    override func resignFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        gradient.colors = [UIColor.white.cgColor]
        super.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var txtEmail: CustomTextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        txtEmail.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
}
```

There is three problem which I am not able to resolve: - 
1- I have set lineWidth 10 but its showing width 10 at corners and at horizontal/vertical only 5.
2- I want to show the gradient from left to right not top to bottom.
3- When I resign, it is not setting white border

[image]

Please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The line is stroked centrally to the path, so 10 pixel width means 5 pixels either side. Your shape is being clipped at the sides, so you need to inset the path.

**Problem 1**

```
let lineWidth: CGFloat = 10   
let rect = bounds.inset.bounds.insetBy(dx: lineWidth / 2, dy: lineWidth / 2)

let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: frame.size.height / 2)
shape.lineWidth = lineWidth
```

Alternatively, if you want the line to be stroked centrally on the path, you'll need to set your `CustomTextField`'s `clipsToBounds = false`

**Problem 2**

To change the angle of the gradient, use the `startPoint` and `endPoint`

```
gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.5)
```

**Problem 3**

Possibly try

```
gradient.colors = [UIColor.white.cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor]
```

Comment: Thanks Ashley, I have tried gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.5) to resolve point 2. But after adding this, no gradient is showing.

Comment: Dis you try any other values?

Answer (score 1):

First select "NO Border in XCode's element inspector"

then use below code

```
    let lineWidth: CGFloat = 1
    let rect = myTextField.bounds.insetBy(dx: lineWidth / 2, dy: lineWidth / 2)

    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: myTextField.frame.size.height / 2)

    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame =  CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: myTextField.frame.size)
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.green.cgColor, UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.green.cgColor]
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.5)

    let shape = CAShapeLayer()
    shape.lineWidth = lineWidth

    shape.path = path.cgPath
    shape.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    shape.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    gradient.mask = shape

    myTextField.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
```

P.S. This answer is fully inspired by @Ashley's answer.